# Are there as many medial and extremal 3-Erdős-Turán elements in a large set?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $A$ be a large set. Say it contains $k$-Erdős-Turán elements if $A$ contains infinitely many maximal (in other words, it is not a subsequence of an arithmetic progression of greater length) arithmetic progressions of length $k$, a $k$-Erdős-Turán element being any element of such an arithmetic progression. As the case $k=3$ has now been proven, let's refine this by saying that a $3$-Erdős-Turán element is extremal if it is either the smallest or the largest element of a maximal arithmetic progression of length $3$, and medial otherwise. There are asymptotically twice as many extremal $3$-Erdős-Turán elements as medial $3$-Erdős-Turán elements if $3$ is the largest $k$ such that $A$ contains infinitely many maximal arithmetic progressions of length $k$ (which is equivalent to the non-existence of $k'$-Erdős-Turán elements for $k'>3$).

My question is thus: are there actually asymptotically as many medial and extremal $3$-Erdős-Turán elements? Or can we prove that the proportion of medial $3$-Erdős-Turán elements is greater than $1/3$?